# Close modal after progress complete automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I want to show a progressing or loading screen in Google Slide using GAS.
Below script is working fine but i am not getting how to remove the x close icon and also how to close the modal automatically after my process complete (which i am doing with GAS internally).

**show_progress.gs**

```
var htmlOutput = HtmlService
                    .createHtmlOutput('<p>Loading...</p><style>.modal-dialog-title-close{display:none;}</style')
                .setWidth(250)
                .setHeight(300);

SlidesApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Genera progetto');

...............
.............
..................
..............

google.script.host.close();
```

Comment: I don't think that will work in the presentation.  But one thing for sure is that google.script.host.close() is a client side function not a server side

Comment: If you wish to close a dialog you can alway replace it with another self closing dialog with google.script.host.close() in the window.onload

Comment: Please read up on this: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication

Answer (score 0):

#### Modified script

Here is an example using `setTimeout(callback, time)`

```js
function myFunction() {

  var html = `
  <p>Loading...</p>
  <script>
    setTimeout(google.script.host.close(), 3000);
  </script>
  `

  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
                .createHtmlOutput(html)
                .setWidth(250)
                .setHeight(300);
  SlidesApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Genera progetto');
}
```

As you can see, the `google.script.host.close()` needs to be called on the client-side as part of the html service. It is called as a callback function to run when 3000 ms have passeed.

I am not sure about your "process" though, and how you plan to trigger it. Ideally, you trigger the process from the client-side html, which is done like this:

```
google.script.run.doSomething();
```

Where your function in the .gs file is something like this:

```js
function doSomething() {
   Utilities.sleep(10000);
   return "Complete";
}
```

If you want to make something happen once it has completed, then *from client side html* you:

```js
function onSuccess(return){
    console.log(return);
    google.script.host.close();
}

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).doSomething()
```

So your complete function might look something like this:

```
function myFunction() {

  var html = `
  <p>Loading...</p>
  <script>
    function onSuccess(return){
        console.log(return);
        google.script.host.close();
    }
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).doSomething()
  </script>
  `

  var htmlOutput = HtmlService
                .createHtmlOutput(html)
                .setWidth(250)
                .setHeight(300);
  SlidesApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Genera progetto');
}
```

Remember, it sounds like its better to start the process of "Genera progetto" from the client side. Or else there is no way to communicate from the .gs file to the client side html.

#### References

- [Client-to-server communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)
- [google.script.host.close()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#closing_dialogs_and_sidebars_in_google_apps)